# TV show where kids were forced to kill each other

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched this episode in 2014/2015.
It was a live-action, and it was American.

There was a group of kids who got kidnapped, they were all in the same class.

The kidnappers forced them to participate in some games that would make them kill each other. I can remember that one boy was forced to build a weapon, while another girl was forced to search for a weapon in a maze.

Another small piece of information I remember is that the kids refused to play at first, so to make them cooperate, the kidnappers told them they have the names and information of their families, and if they do not participate they will kidnap their little siblings and force them in those games as well.

Comment: Nice question. I know this isn't your first story identification, but if you want some guidance to make it better, see [the guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999).

Comment: Did it seem to be the first episode? If not, were these kids already kidnapped before this episode, or was all of this new to the specific installment?

Comment: Are there fantasy or SciFi elements to the show?

Comment: Movie Battle Royale (2000) by Director Kinji Fukasaku.

Comment: @Oni no maze, not American, no forced cooperation, no threat on siblings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is similar to an episode of Criminal Minds called "Wheels on the Bus". Season 8 Episode 8.

> The BAU launches a massive search when a school bus full of students disappears outside the Washington, D.C. area. As the search continues, they uncover a twisted motive for the mass abduction.

The girl who finds a weapon and the boy who assembles one.

> Joshua directs Addyson to a room where she finds the dead body of Carol Roberts, with a key slung over her neck. He orders Addyson to retrieve the key, threatening that he will kill her family if she doesn't comply. This prompts Addyson to get the key and put it around her neck as instructed. She is then guided to a room with two boxes, one locked and the other unlocked. There, she finds Trent hurriedly loading an unloaded handgun found in the unlocked box. At Joshua's urging, Addyson unlocks the locked box, retrieves the handgun inside, and kills Trent, an act that horrifies her.